# Backup SQL Server database using WITH FORMAT

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the purpose of the `WITH FORMAT` option of the SQL Server `BACKUP DATABASE` command.

Using the MSDN example:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
    TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.Bak'
       WITH FORMAT,
            MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',
            NAME = 'Full Backup of AdventureWorks2012';
GO
```

I understand this deletes any existing backups and creates a new one.

If I was to omit the `WITH FORMAT` line, and I already had a backup at `Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.Bak`, what does this mean to my backup?

Is it incremental or does it overwrite with a full one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a full backup, essentially appended to the file if it exists already, you'll see a File number 2 reference when you run it, and you'll see the backup file double in size. Each backup is independent of each other and either can be restored.

Comment: Thanks for response. If i was to `RESTORE FROM DISK` where the backup has been appended which backup is restored?

Comment: The most recent, unless you specify a sequence. Personally I think the appended files are a pain and prefer unique, timestamped file each day.